# Hidden functions in global environment?

Tags: r

When creating a package, I usually use `package.skeleton`. Reading its help, it says that:

> Functions with names starting with a dot are placed in file
>   ‘R/name-internal.R’.

I have just created a test skeleton with an "empty" workspace, running `rm(list=ls())` before `package.skeleton("test")`.

It turns out that it created the `test-internal.R` with a lot of "functions/objects" starting with dots, for example: `.getSymbols`, `.GoogleGeocodeQueryCount`, `.Random.seed` etc.

Are these hidden objects in the .GlobalEnvironment? Why they do not show up in `ls()`?

Comment: you can see them with `ls(all = TRUE)`

Comment: Which is just short for `ls(all.names=TRUE)`. To really clear the global environment, do `rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))`.

Comment: I always forget what comes after "all" anyway but the shorthand still works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rawr and Josh have said, this was pretty simple, just use `ls(all.names=TRUE)` to list all objects on the environment. So, to make sure that the  global environment is clear, `rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))`.